# addition/subtraction of TensorFlow loss Python,

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I try to implement the feature unlearning technique provided by [https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.11577]
For that I need to subtract the loss differences of two learning steps.
Here the equation I want to implement in the end.

[image: The equation I want to implement]

And here the part of my sandbox code how I think is relevant.

```
for step,   (x_batch_retrain, y_batch_retrain) in enumerate(retrain_dataset):
       
            #Open a GradientTape to record teh operations run
            #during the forward pass, which enables auto-differantation
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                #Run the forward pass of the layer
                # Tahe operations that the layer appies
                # to its inputs are going the be recored
                # on the GradientTape
                logitsTilde = model(x_batch_retrain, training= True)    #the new values / z~   

                # Compute the loss value of this minibatch
                loss_value_ZTilde = loss_fn(y_batch_retrain, logitsTilde)


        for step,   (x_batch_unlearn, y_batch_unlearn) in enumerate(unlearn_dataset):
                  
            #Open a GradientTape to record teh operations run
            #during the forward pass, which enables auto-differantation
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                #Run the forward pass of the layer
                # Tahe operations that the layer appies
                # to its inputs are going the be recored
                # on the GradientTape
                logitsZ = model(x_batch_unlearn, training= True)        #the old values / z

                # Compute the loss value of this minibatch
                loss_value_Z = loss_fn(y_batch_unlearn, logitsZ)

        #lossges = loss_value_Z
        lossges = model.compile(loss = [loss_value_Z, loss_value_ZTilde], loss_weights=[1,1])  
        #lossges = tf.math.subtract(loss_value_Z, loss_value_ZTilde)
        #lossges = loss_value_ZTilde - loss_value_Z

        #Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss
        grads = tape.gradient(lossges, model.trainable_weights)
```

I tried with different functions but always get an error. How can I subtract the loss?
"-"- Operator -> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
model.compile-> TypeError: Argument `target` should be a list or nested structure of Tensors, Variables or CompositeTensors to be differentiated, but received None. But I don't have a target variable
tf.math.subtract ->  ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Comment: `model.compile()` is not used for loss computation directly, and for the `loss` parameter you should give a loss function, not the loss itself. It should also be called one time before the training, not during the training loop.